# Modify Dynamic Field Display Length in OTRS

Tags: otrs

I've added a dropdown field to a customer's ticket in OTRS called Branch. It allows users to select their branch, identified by a number and a name. For example, my branch is `901 - Support Group`. When I display this field in the ticket zoom view on the Agent side, it gets truncated to `901 - Support[...]`. I can see the entire value of the field as a hover text when I hold my mouse over it, but I was hoping there would be a setting to expand the length of the field or to tell OTRS to display it as multiline text. Is there a configuration option in OTRS to change the display length, or does anyone know where I would need to modify the code to change the length myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from crythias over at the OtterHub forums, I was able to find the right setting.

1. Navigate to the SysConfig
2. Filter by the Ticket config group (dropdown on left)
3. Locate and select Frontend::Agent
4. Locate Ticket::Frontend::DynamicFieldsZoomMaxSizeSidebar

By default this is set to 18 characters. I reset it to 140 (Twitter rules), and it automatically wrapped the text for me.